# MySQL Outer Left Join with Criteria for Second Table

Tags: mysql, join

**Table 1 - Golfers**

golferID

golferName

**Table 2 - Picks**

golferID

userID

---

I want to select all Golfers who have not been picked yet by a certain userID. The Picks table could have 20 entries for one golferID.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want all Golfers who have not been picked yet by userID 3, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM Golfers g
WHERE g.golferID NOT IN (
    SELECT p.golferID FROM Picks p
    WHERE p.userID = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
select G.golferId, G.golferName
from Golfers G left join Picks P 
on G.golferId = P.golferId 
where P.userId != 'certain_user_id' or P.userId is NULL
```